# I can't install Netbeans10

Tags: java, netbeans

As a beginner for java,I found it's easy to install Netbeans8 but not Netbeans10.It seemed that I need to deal with the documents I downloaded.Here are the instuctions from the website of Netbeans but I don't understand why I can't install it.Please help me know how to deal with it.
To build Apache NetBeans (incubating) 10.0 from source you need:
Oracle’s Java 8 or Open JDK v8.
Apache Ant 1.10 or greater (https://ant.apache.org).
Once you have everything installed then:
Unzip incubating-netbeans-10.0-source.zip in a directory of your liking.
cd to that directory, and then run ant to build the Apache NetBeans IDE. Once built you can run the IDE by typing ./nbbuild/netbeans/bin/netbeans

Comment: When I downloaded NB 10 I didn't install it. I think it comes ready to run.

Comment: Thank you for answer me so quickly!Then which item did you download from the website of Netbeans,incubating-netbeans-10.0-source or incubating-netbeans-10.0-bin?Can you expiain the instructions from the website of NB for me?And how do you open the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the bin folder from [here](ftp://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/ftp.apache.org/dist/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans/incubating-10.0/incubating-netbeans-10.0-bin.zip) and place it where you want your Netbeans installation to be.

Go to the bin folder and execute the IDE (NetBeans or netbeans64.exe which is depending on your system).

If you having trouble and NetBeans says it can't find your java SDK head to the etc folder and open the config file (netbeans.conf).

There you find a line that looks like this: `#netbeans_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"`
Change that line to the path where your Java SDK is installed and DONT forget to remove the hashtag because then its referenced as a comment.

At the end it should like something like this: `netbeans_jdkhome="C:/Programm Files/Java/jdk.x.x.x"`

I Hope I could help you